# Team Foundation Server, ebooks or starting points

Tags: tfs

I would like to learn how to use TFS2010, but I can't find any recent ebook. Could you give me some advices, or can you aim me to starting resources / tutorials about this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010 (Wrox)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484268)

I believe it's also available as e-book.

Comment: +1. One more for my *Have to read* list.

Comment: I'm reading it by now. It is a good book.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5.aspx) is actually a good resource, if not the easiest to navigate.

I created an outline of all the MSDN documentation for TFS 2010 [here](http://leonardwoody.com/2010/07/19/outline-of-msdn-application-lifecycle-management-library-for-visual-studio-2010/).

Answer (score 1):

I've pre-ordered Pro Team Foundation Server 2010: [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Team-Foundation-Server-2010/dp/0470943327/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1291305818&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470943327)

Comment: +1.  This and ALM with VS2010 are both great.